# 覚せい剤 - why is it written with kana?

Tags: kanji, orthography, kana

Why is 覚せい剤 a common variant writing of 覚醒剤? 醒 is a Joyo kanji and wouldn't pose any recognition problems.

Example: 
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/覚せい剤取締法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%9B%E3%81%84%E5%89%A4%E5%8F%96%E7%B7%A0%E6%B3%95)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [醒 was not a 常用漢字 until 2010](https://www.coscom.co.jp/japanesekanji/newjoyokanji-j.html). 覚せい剤取締法 has been around long before that.

According to [覚醒剤 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A6%9A%E9%86%92%E5%89%A4#.E5.B8.B8.E7.94.A8.E6.BC.A2.E5.AD.97.E3.81.AE.E5.95.8F.E9.A1.8C):

> 覚醒の「醒」が「せい」と表記されるのは、2010年まで常用漢字ではなかったためである

And according to [覚せい剤取締法 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%9B%E3%81%84%E5%89%A4%E5%8F%96%E7%B7%A0%E6%B3%95#.E5.90.8D.E7.A7.B0):

> 「醒」の文字は2010年に改定されて常用漢字となり、法律の条文や法律名を除き一般名詞としては、覚醒の文字を報道でも用いるよう合意がなされている。
>   麻薬及び向精神薬取締法においては、2013年に表記が覚醒剤に改められている。